# How to target a specific <li>

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I would like to target the following "list" items seperately and amend the href's individually  for each. However, I would like to do it without the "list"'s having a specific div tag/class. Is it possible?

```
<li><a href="javascript:;">Category 1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;">Category 2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;">Category 3</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using jquery, you can do something like this:

```
$.each($("li a"), function(){
     var href = $(this).attr('href');
     var text = $(this).text();
     //now you have your href and text
     if(text == 'Category 1'){
        //updated to change the link to a different URL
        $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.your-new-link');
     }
     if(text == 'Category 2'){
        //do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, this sounds like its along the right track, however, I am not very familiar with jquery. How would I then make it change the href to a different website link/path?

Comment: Updated the answer to change the link